# Enable Submit Button If All Checkboxes Are Checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fetching my data from Json tables in form of list.The submit button should be enabled only when all the check boxes are checked.
this is my code.
Html:

```
 <ol>
 <li  ng-repeat='box in Box.json'  id='box' >
 <input type="checkbox"  value='{{box.id}}'>{{box.name}}</li>
 </ol>
```

//Javascript:

```
 $scope.check=function(){
     return ($scope.check1 && $scope.check2 && $scope.check3)   
  }
```

The above scope variables are ng-models of each

.But since the  data is displayed in list using ng-repeat,I am not able to put ng-model for each and every row from table.Therefore the return statement is not affective and even after checking all checkboxes submit button is not enabled.And I am not supposed to use Jquery.Please Help

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHYpC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just adjust your `box` object directly and then reduce your array of objects to a boolean value to see if all the checkboxes are checked.

```
 <ol>
   <li  ng-repeat='box in Box.json'  id='box'>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="box.checked"> {{box.name}}
   </li>
 </ol>
```

And your check function.

```
$scope.check=function(){
  return $scope.Box.json.reduce(function(prev,value){
    if(!prev) return false;
    return value.checked && true || false;
  },true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your btn

```
ng-disabled="!check"
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.